# Arbitrary Timeline in Cesium?

Tags: maps, timeline, cesiumjs

Cesium has a nice timeline at the bottom of the screen that changes the current astronomical phenomena and changes model positions and animation based on their model. What it doesn't have, and what I really need, is a way to plot events in arbitrary time. I'd like to start at time 00:00:00, and advance from there in real time, and rewind back to 00:00:00. At the moment, I don't care about astronomical activity, including solar and lunar activity. The API is set up to accept Julian Time, not set up for some arbitrary time. Is it possible to get an arbitrary timeline inserted in place of the normal timeline?

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try.  Internally it still uses JulianDates from some arbitrary date, but the user only ever sees the time, not the date.

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    navigationInstructionsInitiallyVisible: false,
    skyBox: false
});

var clock = viewer.clock;
clock.clockRange = Cesium.ClockRange.LOOP_STOP;
clock.startTime = Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601('2016-01-01T00:00:00Z');
clock.stopTime  = Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601('2016-01-01T23:59:59Z');
clock.currentTime = clock.startTime;

function twoDigits(num) {
    return ((num < 10) ? ('0' + num.toString()) : num.toString());
}

var animationViewModel = viewer.animation.viewModel;
animationViewModel.dateFormatter = function() { return ''; };

animationViewModel.timeFormatter = function(date, viewModel) {
    var gregorianDate = Cesium.JulianDate.toGregorianDate(date);
    var millisecond = Math.round(gregorianDate.millisecond);
    return Cesium.sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", gregorianDate.hour,
        gregorianDate.minute, gregorianDate.second, millisecond);
};

viewer.timeline.makeLabel = function(time) {
    var gregorian = Cesium.JulianDate.toGregorianDate(time);
    var millisecond = gregorian.millisecond, millisecondString = '';
    if ((millisecond > 0) && (this._timeBarSecondsSpan < 3600)) {
        millisecondString = Math.floor(millisecond).toString();
        while (millisecondString.length < 3) {
            millisecondString = '0' + millisecondString;
        }
        millisecondString = '.' + millisecondString;
    }

    return twoDigits(gregorian.hour) + ':' + twoDigits(gregorian.minute) + ':' +
        twoDigits(gregorian.second) + millisecondString;
};

viewer.timeline.updateFromClock();
viewer.timeline.zoomTo(clock.startTime, clock.stopTime);
```

```css
html, body, #cesiumContainer {
    width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.18/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.18/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js">
</script>
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
```